# Zend Framework1, Is there a way to override Zend_View_Helper_* functions per Controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, view-helpers

I have a View Helper like below and it is working perfectly fine:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_List extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function list()
    {
        return '<ul><li>Something Really Good</li></ul>'; // generated html 
    }
}
```

I have this in my global layout `myapp.phtml`:

```
<div><?php echo $this->list(); ?></div>
```

My question is how can I override `list()` in different controller or even more granular, each controller action?

I have tried to set a View variable in each controller e.g. `$this->view->type` and then pass it to the list function `<div><?php echo $this->list($this->type); ?></div>`, but it looks dirty and not right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your helpers in a `view/helpers` folder of specific Controller so it will be visible for this controller only.

You can also add new path for Helpers `$this->view->setHelperPath('MyScripts/View/Helper/','MyScripts_View_Helper');` if you need to change it per Action.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have a single view helper you can effectively use variables.
You can try something like this:

In your foo action:

```
$this->view->type = 'action_foo';
```

In your View Helper:

```
public function list()
{
    if (isset($this->view->type)){
        if ('action_foo' == $this->view->type)
            return '<ul><li>Something Really Good for Foo Action</li></ul>'; // generated html 
        else
            return '<ul><li>' . $this->view->type . '</li></ul>'; // generated html 
    }
    else
        return '<ul><li>Something Really Good</li></ul>'; // generated html 
}
```